# How should I represent "global" events / observances / occasions in Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

I administer an educational site that includes a calendar of global events, but these are not "Events" in the sense that Schema.org's Event type considers them – they don't have a location, and they are observed across a wide area (e.g. a country, an continent, or worldwide). They are more like global anniversaries, occasions or observances. Examples include Earth Day, Chinese New Year, World Book Day, International Women's Day and so on.

In our initial attempt at introducing microdata for these calendar pages, I have used the Event type, but I'm aware that as many – or most – of these events don't have a definable location (in the sense that Schema.org represents a location), and are not "attended" in a physical or digital sense, they cannot be valid.

Is there a more appropriate type in the Schema.org vocabulary that I should use in this case? Is it inappropriate to try to represent them in Schema.org microdata at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe **[Google's guide for an online event](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event#online-event)** can help you, including an example:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Adventures of Kira and Morrison</title>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison",
      "startDate": "2025-07-21T19:00:00-05:00",
      "endDate": "2025-07-21T23:00-05:00",
      "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/EventScheduled",
      "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OnlineEventAttendanceMode",
      "location": {
        "@type": "VirtualLocation",
        "url": "https://operaonline.stream5.com/"
        },
      "image": [
        "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
        "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
       ],
      "description": "The Adventures of Kira and Morrison is coming to Snickertown in a can't miss performance.",
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "https://www.example.com/event_offer/12345_201803180430",
        "price": "30",
        "priceCurrency": "USD",
        "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
        "validFrom": "2024-05-21T12:00"
      },
      "performer": {
        "@type": "PerformingGroup",
        "name": "Kira and Morrison"
      },
      "organizer": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "Kira and Morrison Music",
        "url": "https://kiraandmorrisonmusic.com"
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

In addition, Schema has the beta version of the type **[VirtualLocation](https://schema.org/VirtualLocation)**.

Comment: Thanks for this – do you think the `Location` field ought to contain a reference to the page this content is on as its `url`? A valid Event needs to provide a location – these occasions/observances are not really "attended" as such but I can see the sense in referring to the page hosting this content.

Comment: It depends on the context, that is, the content of the page that your data is linking to.

Comment: The specific case here is a calendar of global events, e.g. Earth Day, with detail pages for each describing general details about the event. These are the pages hosting the microdata – so I suppose my distilled question is: for an event that can't be physically or digitally attended, would it be considered valid to have its "location" be the page hosting the general content about the event?

Comment: The calendar is a list. But each event requires a separate page. Google prohibits marking the list with a top-level type such as Event.

Comment: That part is fine and understood – I just mean the event pages themselves. I think we're pretty much in agreement – an "online event" is a reasonable model for what we're trying to represent here, and the mandatory `location` field may as well refer to the current page, since that's where the content representing the event is.